# PhpStorm 2017.1 gets the PHPUnit-Path wrong while reading vendor/autoload.php

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

I am trying to execute PHPUnit within Vagrant with PhpStorm 2017.
I am able to run PHPUnit via SSH (Putty).

I've set up a remote PHP interpreter, which correctly displays "PHP version: 5.6.31-4+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+4". When I navigate to Settings/Languages/PHPUnit, select "Use Composer Autoloader" and enter the path to `/mnt/asf/vendor/autoload.php`, it displays

```
Can not parse PHPUnit version output: Could not open input file: /mnt/asf/vendorphpunitphpunitphpunit
```

As you can see it basically **gets the path mostly right, but somehow drops the slashes.**

I suspected the fact that the host is Windows (backslashes used) and that path is in a shared folder. But then on the other hand, everything happens via remote connection in a Linux environment.

Any hints welcome. Thanks

(Please do not mark as duplicate with questions more than 2 years old. PhpStorm only recently added that composer option.)

Comment: Please try latest 2017.2.4 version. This could be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35806 .. which supposed to be fixed even in 2017.1.4

Comment: @LazyOne: Perfect, that's it. Thanks! (Feel free to copy it into an answer so I can accept it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try latest **2017.2.4** version.

Based on description this could be [WI-35806](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35806) .. which supposed to be fixed even in 2017.1.4.